# Blender scripting loop not working

Tags: python, scripting, camera, workflow, loop

I'm trying to set the camera to always look the origin of the scene and then I want to rotate the camera about the origin to get a new camera pose (i.e. rotate the empty point the camera is looking at in the origin).

This works when I do it without a loop:

```
b_empty = scene.objects["Empty"]      
b_empty.rotation_euler[2] += math.radians(360/20)
print(cam.matrix_world)
```

But when I do it in a loop it doesn't work and the camera stays the same (same print for cam.matrix_world)

```
for i in range(20):
    b_empty = scene.objects["Empty"]     
    b_empty.rotation_euler[2] += math.radians(360/20)
    print(cam.matrix_world)
```

what could be going wrong?

Comment: You don't do anything to `cam` in your script. Why do you expect it to change? Also why do you need the loop? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: you need make sure `obj.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'` and run `bpy.context.view_layer.update() ` before you access the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately your problem could be described as:

```py
my_var = 3
my_var += 1
print(my_var % 10)  # it changed!

for i in range(10):
    my_var += 1
print(my_var % 10)  # it didn't change!
```

Except in your case you don't use modulo; your equivalent to the modulo is, however, the periodic nature of rotation: rotating by $360°$ is the same as not rotating at all. `range(20)` produces 20 numbers, and for each you rotate by $360\over20$, so the resulting rotation is $20{360\over20}$ degrees; twenties cancel out and you're left with exactly one full rotation.

**If you inspect your object's rotation, it has changed. You just don't see it, because an object rotated by 360° looks the same way as before rotation.**